# when i compile it tells me cannot find symbol- class Stock. why is this so?

Tags: java

when i compile it tells me cannot find symbol- class Stock. why is this so? This isn't the complete code and i am using Blue J. thanks

```
    import java.util.*;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    public class SRunner
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    sc.useDelimiter("\n");

    String ans;
    String cont;
    int option;
    String code2;
    ArrayList<Stock>StockList;  new ArrayList<Stock>();
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with javascript. You should remove that tag. ;)

Comment: Nor arrays. Nor the Java compiler API, nor debugging as far as I can tell.

Comment: Where did you *expect* to find the `Stock` class? You've told us nothing about it.

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing a class called `Stock` in your code, however, the compiler is telling you that it cannot find this class. This might be because you've forgotten to import it, or because you've made a spelling mistake in the name.

Also, you are not actually assigning the new instance of `ArrayList<>` to a variable; that final line of code should probably look like,

```
ArrayList<Stock> StockList = new ArrayList<Stock>();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Compiler is telling you that you are refering to a class Stock, but it is not defined or not on compile-time classpath.**

Comment: The compiler isn't saying that the OP is *defining* a class called `Stock`, but trying to *use* it. (Why have you put your answer in bold?)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a class you are creating, you need to define it in the scope of where you are trying to use it (similar to your SRunner class) or you need to import the correct file/library where 'Stock' is defined.